# How can I know on which drive is Windows installed?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10

I have two exact copies of Windows 10, one on drive C: and one on drive D:. These are two internal drives in the same laptop.

How can I know which Windows is running?

How can I select the one to launch during boot?

Comment: I dont know why you ended up with two exact copies of same version of windows. But for your question on `How can I select the one to launch during boot?` . you can use `easybcd` software [here](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)

Comment: open task manager, select windows system process, then open file location

Comment: @Vishwa - If you write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Type `set` at a command prompt and look at the `windir` variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The drive letters like C: are only assigned during Runtime of a Windows installation, so they will usually be both `C:` for both your installations.

Open an elevated `cmd.exe` or `Powershell.exe` (as Administrator), then type:

```
diskpart
```

after a moment, type:

```
list volume
```

You get something like this:

```
 Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
 ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
 Volume 1         WinBOOT      FAT32  Partition    350 MB  Healthy    System
 Volume 2     D   Win1         NTFS   Partition     31 GB  Healthy
 Volume 3     C   Win2         NTFS   Partition     33 GB  Healthy    Boot
 Volume 4     S   Data         NTFS   Partition    380 GB  Healthy
```

In this case you can see that the Windows on `Volume 3` is currently running, there is another one on `Volume 2`, `Boot` in the Info column on the far right indicates that this is the current Windows Drive.

you can see the same by open Disk Management:

```
 diskmgmt.msc
```

and look for `Boot` in the Status column of volumes.

When setting up a dual boot Windows you should use descriptive names for each boot entry.

Comment: @Scott - Yes, I am saying the `Boot` in the Info column indicates the Windows drive and I did say that above. It is usually the C: drive, but doesn't have to be.

Comment: I found what I was looking for in `diskmgmt.msc`, but strangely, I couldn't find any drive with an Info value of `Boot` when I ran `list volume`. Maybe that's because the info was truncated? It doesn't appear so, but the Label column is definitely truncated. Is there a way to run `list volume` without truncation? I don't see anything here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/list

Answer (score 6):

There are a few ways, and I'll mention the quickest ways that come into my mind.

1. Open Run dialog (<kbd>Winkey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and type the below command and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it'll open your current Windows installation directory

   ```
   %windir%
   ```
2. Open Task manager and select a system process (something like svchost.exe or winlogon.exe) in Details/Processes tab. Right click on that and you can see Open File Location, which will also open your windows directory.

Comment: +Also, if you have windows vista or later, your boot drive will show a windows logo/flag when you open the My computer, Computer or This PC (Name may vary depending on the OS version)

Comment: Whether he boots his C:\Windows or his D:\Windows, when running both will display C:\Windows as the file location. Because nearly all Windows installations are in C:\Windows now.

Answer (score 4):

Some other ways

- Open the run dialog with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `\` then Enter. That'll show your Windows drive. (Tip: running `.` will show your home folder and `..` will show your users folder)
- Open start menu, type "system info" and open **System Information**. You'll see the ***Windows Directory*** under *System Summary*
- Open start menu, type "disk management" or press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> > diskmgmt.msc > Enter. That'll list all the drives in your PC. The system drive will be listed with the **Boot** flag, most likely along with "Crash Dump" and "Page File"
- Simply press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and run cmd. The path to cmd.exe is often shown on the title bar by default. On some systems it simply shows "Command Prompt" but in that case you can look at the prompt string which often points to your user folder in the system drive

  [image: cmd with path in title]

  This is quick but not reliable either, so while you're at the commmand prompt just run the commands in other answers or you can run `echo %systemroot%` or `set sys`

  ```
  C:\>set sys
  SystemDrive=C:
  SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
  ```
- Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd> or right click My Computer > Properties > System Protection. Your system drive will be listed with the word "System"

  [image: system protection]

That said, nowadays Windows often shows its system drive always as C: regardless of its system volume position in a drive, so a drive label or device name is more useful than a drive letter

Answer (score 3):

There are many options to do as others users told

A simplest option I use to identify OS in drive in multi boot is to **right click the Windows start menu and click explore and the profile directory** opens for the user and I got to know the drive letter from which I booted the OS

I have 2 Windows 10, 2 Windows 7 and 3 Windows XP installed and modified boot menu and categorised it and named it like Windows 10 for C drive (study), Windows 10 for D drive (games), Windows 10 for e drive (banking), Windows 10 for f drive (downloading)

**You can modify boot menu with the following way**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/changing-the-friendly-name-of-a-boot-entry

https://youtu.be/RICVlbN5phE

**Secondly I run CMD which to opens in the default directory system directory where windows installed**

Thirdly as told by other users following ways and commands and variables to know it

1. `diskmgmt.msc`
2. `%windir%`
   3. `echo %systemroot%`
3. `wmic OS GET SystemDrive /VALUE`

Comment: The only answer that tries to address the menu part of the question

Answer (score 1):

Open CMD an Type in `wmic OS GET SystemDrive /VALUE`

This Will Return System Drive Letter.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to bring up the Run command box.

Type in the command `msconfig` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>,

This will bring up system configuration settings. Click on the 'Boot' tab.

Answer (score 1):

Open CMD, type "set" hit enter,...locate desired info;
HOMEDRIVE, SystemDrive, SystemRoot, etc.

And other one by(cmd);
systeminfo | findstr Directory && systeminfo | find "Boot Device"

Dont dwell with diskpart, you might get bad info, ie;
[diskpart misleading partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6FtN.png)